# Как отловить, каким элементом формы вызвано событие change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть форма. На форме висит событие `change`, по которому создается ajax-запрос к серверу с сериализованным значением формы. Но мне нужно кроме сериарилизованных значений формы знать имя элемента, изменением которого было вызвано событие:

```
$('form').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/calc',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function () {},
        error: function () {},
    });
});
```

Из очевидного - можно запоминать состояние формы между запросами, а перед запросом сравнивать сериализованные значения и находить имя измененного элемента. Но может есть проще варианты?

Пример формы не привожу, потому что она у меня генерируется бэкендом и может включать в себя что угодно - input text, input checkbox, select, select multiple и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('form').on('change', function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).attr('name'));
}
```

Comment: да, спасибо. я как раз вернулся, чтоб снять вопрос. уже внимательно почитал доку.